# Animate View on Menu Button Tap using Swift 2

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7, ios-animations

I got a Home Page in my App which has a Menu button(Hamburger) on the Right of the Screen. My Requirement is to Animate the Current View(Home Screen or Profile Screen or Settings Screen ) on Tapping the Menu Button. On Tapping The Menu Button which Screen is Currently Active Should Animate. 
The Requirement Screen Looks like the Image Below 
[image]

The Image shows how the  Screen looks like after tapping the Menu button.
ie: if Home Screen is active then the home screen should animate , if it is a profile screen which is active then the profile screen should animate. Can i make animations like this using Swift2. Currently i am using Xcode 7. For menu i am looking forward to use SWRealViewController. if i use SWrealViewController can i achieve this effect ? Or is there any third party Tool available ?

Comment: DownVote !!! People who Downvotes question Can you guys make it clear why You guys Downvotes a question? to the guy who downvoted the question how can i improve this question???

Answer (score 1):

After a long Search for what i needed i just came to find a library. [ITRAirSideMenu](https://github.com/ITechRoof/ITRAirSideMenu)

Which is exactly what i was in search for.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Third party Library. Hope it helps you

https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/DLHamburguerMenu

Comment: I am Using SWrevealViewController right now. https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController . but my requirement is to animate the view like in my question.